# SSL certificate in tomcat and apache ( use in both)

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I have SSL wildcard certificate.
I have tomcat as well as apache server running on my machine.
Currently ssl has been applied on tomcat but apache being my wrapper server needs ssl certificate too.
Both apache and tomcat are on same machine.
Can I use same wildcard for both of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use same Wildcard SSL certificate (but for only one domain such as *.domain.com) for both tomcat and Apache server. Even you can use the same wildcard SSL certificate for different server too.

Comment: with all due respect , can you confirm this by providing some source or more explanation . Thanks :)